# How can I register a new user with a user-defined unique identifier when leveraging OAuth code flow?

Tags: c#, security, encryption, authentication

I'm building a sign-up / login flow for a web site. I plan to use Facebook as my identity provider instead of rolling my own.

I have a good feel for the server-side login flow with Facebook:

1. Call FB [login API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.2#login) to get a code
2. [Exchange the code](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.2#confirm) for a user access token
3. [Inspect](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.2#checktoken) the user access token
4. Validate the user access token details

After these steps, I'd like to check if the authenticated user is already registered in my system. If yes, simply return a newly generated bearer token, so the user can make subsequent requests to resource servers to access protected data.

If the user is not registered in the system, however, then I'd like to register them by creating a database entry. Before creating this entry though, I'd like to collect one piece of information from the user. Namely, I'd like for them to tell me their desired 'username'. I will use this unique username as my database primary key.

I'm not 100% sure on how to securely ask the user for their desired username before creating the database entry. This is my question. :)

One thought I had was to create a "redemption code". This code would be encrypted and contain the user initialization details, a secret only the server would know, and a timestamp. Something like this:

```
code: {
    mySecret: "super-secret-value",
    expirationDate: "date-value",
    user: { ... },
}
```

After seeing the user is not in my system, I'd respond with the code + redirect the client to a page where they'd be able to specify their username. Upon submitting their username + code back up to the server, I could decrypt the code, and validate `mySecret` to determine the code is not tampered. If all is good, create the user in the database with the `user` information from the redeemed code. Lastly, I'd generate a new bearer token for the user and send it to the client.

**Questions**

1. Is my proposed redemption code strategy a secure way of requesting a username before creating the backend DB entry?
2. If not, what would be?
3. If yes, what is a secure encryption/decryption routine to use for this purpose in C#?

**Flow Sequence**

- Steps 1-4 from above correspond to "Login" through "Validate" arrows.
- My proposed redemption code strategy corresponds to the purple arrows.
- Red text corresponds to Facebook specific nomenclature.

[image]

Note, Stack Overflow does something very similar to what I want to do. Before creating your account on SO, it will ask you for your desired Display Name (this happens after authenticating via Facebook, Google, etc.). After submitting your display name, your account is registered.

Answer (score 0):

Use open source IdentityServer3.

Whatever flow you choose its already standardized in their server. Including (if you want or need) OpenID, OAuth2 etc.